# How to focus a record near a record you've just deleted in DBgrid Delphi?

Tags: database, delphi

I use `TDBgrid` in Delphi and the Dataset is `Adoquery`. I have many record which have the ID from 1 to 1000. Now for example I want to delete the 35th by `TadoQuery` 'Delete from...' Is there any way to immediately focus the 34th or 36th record for the customer to check if the 35th has been deleted.
Here's the code for my delete button

```
StudentID := UniQuery1.FieldValues['StudentID'];
UniQuery1.SQL.Clear();
UniQuery1.SQL.Text :=('Delete from Student where StudentID = ''' + StudentID + '''');
UniQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from Student');
UniQuery1.Execute;
```

Anyone can help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a TClientDataSet (which is a good idea anyway), you can use [FindNearest](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29176).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, save the id of the tuple *previous* to the one that you want to delete. Then delete the tuple that you wish to delete, and afterwards locate the saved tuple. To get to the previous tuple, use uniquery1.moveby (-1).

Answer (score 0):

Save `UniQuery1.RecNo` before deleting. After deleting, re-query the dataset, which should set the first record active, then issue `UniQuery1.MoveBy(SavedRecNo - 1)` or `UniQuery1.MoveBy(SavedRecNo - 2)`, depending on whether you want to move to the record succeeding or preceding the deleted one.